# XML manipulation of elements' text content using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert a number of XML files to a slightly different XML structure. I want to preserve some element content and discard others. Is this possible? I need to manipulate the text content of elements and other questions doesn't seem to do this.
My XML files are similar to this

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            BBB1
            <c>CCCC</c>
            BBB2
            <e>
                DDDD1
                <f>EEEE</f>
                DDDD2
            </e>
            BBB3
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

and I want the output to be

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            CCCC
            <e>
                DDDD1
                EEEE
                DDDD2
            </e>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

My XSL skeleton looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="f">
    <xsl:value-of select="f"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
<root>
    <a>
        <xsl:for-each select="a/b">
            <b>
                <c>
                    <xsl:value-of select="c"/>
                </c>
                <e>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="e"/>
                </e>
            </b>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </a>
</root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- copy everything as-is ... -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ...except for <c> and <f> elements, output their values only -->
  <xsl:template match="c | f">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ...and don't output direct text children from <b> elements -->
  <xsl:template match="b/text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>CCCC<e>
                DDDD1
                EEEE
                DDDD2
            </e></b>
    </a>
</root>
```

Does this already meet your requirements?

Keeping "optically nice" indent in text nodes is not trivial, however, I suppose you don't really depend on that.